# how i can remove folders name from url

Tags: php

Here is my url and i wanted to remove engine-body.php?id=2  to engine-body/2

```
http://localhost/BMW/userSide/series/engine-body.php?id=2
```

also i wanted to remove folders name BMW/userSide

i am able to remove .php extention from file name 
but when i try to remove folder name my url do not work.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^BMW/(.*)$ /$1 [L,NC,R]
```

through this line i am able to remove .php and my urls work fine

```
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

but when i add this line to remove folder name

```
 RewriteRule ^BMW/(.*)$ /$1 [L,NC,R]
```

i am able to remove folder name but my url do not work .Here is my url after this

```
http://localhost/userSide/series/engine-body.php?id=2
```

Comment: Why you tag mysqli into this question??

Comment: A different way of doing it could be explode by `/`, join together again without the middle part, and replace `.php?id=` with `/`

Comment: You got it the wrong way around. Read the duplicate for an explanation of what `RewriteRule` does and the problem should become obvious.